# Can't convert object of type java.lang.Boolean Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I don't have any boolean value in my firebase database but on fetching the data from database to the recycler view it shows Can't convert object of type java.lang.Boolean this type of error,and application crashes after crash if i open the application it starts but again if any value is added in the database the app crashes again

My code

```
 Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Donor");
    model = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ShowDonorDetails>().setQuery(query,ShowDonorDetails.class).build();
    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ShowDonorDetails, ShowDonorDetailsAdapter>(model) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ShowDonorDetailsAdapter holder, int position, @NonNull ShowDonorDetails model) {
            holder.t1.setText(model.getFname());
            holder.t2.setText(model.getLname());
            holder.t3.setText(model.getBloodgroup());
        }
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ShowDonorDetailsAdapter onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.showdonordetails,viewGroup,false);
            return new ShowDonorDetailsAdapter(view);
        }
    };
```

Model class:

```
public class ShowDonorDetails {
String fname,lname,phone,status,enddate,bloodgroup,age,address;

public String getFname() {
    return fname;
}

public void setFname(String fname) {
    this.fname = fname;
}

public String getLname() {
    return lname;
}

public void setLname(String lname) {
    this.lname = lname;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getEnddate() {
    return enddate;
}

public void setEnddate(String enddate) {
    this.enddate = enddate;
}

public String getBloodgroup() {
    return bloodgroup;
}

public void setBloodgroup(String bloodgroup) {
    this.bloodgroup = bloodgroup;
}

public String getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(String age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public ShowDonorDetails(String fname, String lname, String phone, String status, String enddate, String bloodgroup, String age, String address) {
    this.fname = fname;
    this.lname = lname;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.status = status;
    this.enddate = enddate;
    this.bloodgroup = bloodgroup;
    this.age = age;
    this.address = address;
}

public ShowDonorDetails() {
}
```

my Logcat: [image]

my Database : [image]

can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You're telling FirebaseUI that the child nodes of  `Donor` are all `ShowDonorDetails` objects, and it looks like at least one child node under `Donor` is instead a single boolean value. You'll need to ensure each child node is a `ShowDonorDetails` object to make this work.

Comment: But there are no such boolean values under child node "Donor"

Comment: The error message seems to indicate otherwise. You might want to see if you can catch the error, to determine exactly where it happens.

Comment: I just solved that error, but I don't think that can be the best solution for it, before Query part i just added the database reference query to my exact Donor node and now it doesn't crashes i don't know what might be the exact issue but for now it's working good.